# Refresh or reload uitabbar and my whole application in iphone when user logout

Tags: iphone

I have login and logout feature in my application. when user logout then i switch user from my home screen to logout screen. but when i login a user with different account then previous user information displays for some seconds because i have timer in my application when timer execute then user information would update. I feel this issue is due to tabbarcontroller which is loading from .Xib file and it is not reloading when user login again. I want to refresh and reload my whole application when user logout and login again. I have already release tabbarcontroller but it is not effecting on this situation. Please if any one has any suggestion and solution then help me.

Regards,
Shumais-ul-haq

Comment: Avoid using NSTimer when handling data in an event driven object oriented application. It will make things look quirky to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a timer, you don't need it. Clear out any data so that when viewDidLoad is called there's nothing there (clear textfields, labels, etc.)

Comment: Actually all my data is coming from server side after specific time so timer is necessary to to use in my situation.